# SQL Server : get data where date + last 2 financial years

Tags: sql, sql-server

I wish to find data from where current date and also include data from the last 2 financial years

Basically I want data going back from 'today' to 01/04/2019. I want to add this line of data to dynamically happen, not just a one off for the future

Thus if the date today was 05/06/2022, I would want the date going from that date, backwards until what would be 01/04/2020

The column name is `Date` - please help

Comment: What date is `01/04/2019`?  Would that be in January or April?  **Use ISO standard dates, YYYY-MM-DD.** Please edit your question so the question is clearly defined.  What is definition of "financial year"?

Comment: Most of the people on this site will read that date as January 4. A smaller but significant group here will read it as April 1.

Comment: financial year is 01/04/2019- 31/03/2020 for example... I wish for the data to go from today, include additionally 2 years of financial year data.. so data from 22/06/2021 backwards until 01/04/2019. when the todays date becomes 01/01/2022...I wish for data to be from that date until 01/04/2020 ...please help  @Gordon Linoff

Answer (score 0):

I am quite sure that it should be possible to do it in some simpler way, but you can use something like below:

```
declare @b  date 

set @b = datefromparts(year(getdate()),4,1) --first daty of fiscal year in current calendar year
select case when @b<getdate() then dateadd(year,-2,@b) else dateadd(year,-3,@b) end
```